# Maximal element of a Pythagorean quadruple

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From Legendre's three-square theorem, we know that solutions to
$$
 n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
exist for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ except when $n$ is of the form $4^a(8b + 7)$
for nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$.  Legendre's result admits the possibility
that any of $x,y,z$ can be zero.  In his book "Pythagorean Triangles"
(https://www.softouch.on.ca/kb/data/Pythagorean%20Triangles.pdf), W. Sierpinski
proved on pp. 99-101 that solutions to
$$
 m^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2, m,x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}
$$
do not exist when $m$ is of the form $2^k$ or $2^k(5).$  Since no square mod 8
is 7, Legendre's exclusion doesn't apply to $m$.  Therefore, if $m$ is of one of
these forms, there must be a solution where one or more of $x,y,z$ is zero.  In
fact, we have
$$
 0 + [2^k(3)]^2 + [2^k(4)]^2 = [2^k(5)]^2
$$
and trivially,
$$
 0 + 0 + [2^k]^2 = [2^k]^2
$$
Legendre's result seems to cover the case for other $m \in \mathbb{N},$ and
Sierpinski also states that A. Hurwitz proved that all other natural numbers $m$
can be the maximal element.  However, no reference is given for Hurwitz's
proof.  Can someone post Hurwitz's proof or a link to it, if it is essentially
different than Legendre's three-square theorem?

Comment: I thought that the three square theorem was finally proved by Gauß. I would call it "Gauß-Legendre Theorem".

Comment: I don't quite get the statement of what Hurwitz is supposed to have proved. Please include the complete statement of it in your question for maximum clarity.

Comment: Is the claim Hurwitz proved that for any $m$ which is not $2^k$ or $2^k(5)$, there are $x,y,z \in \Bbb N$ such that $m^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Yes, that's correct.